# unable to start lxc container

Tags: mount, lxc

I have installed lxc in ubuntu server, every thing was working fine. Today I have updated lxc from version 0.7.5 to version 1.0.0.alpha2. After I update lxc, I am unable to start lxc containers.

```
lxc-ls:

ContainerOne containerTwo ContainerThree.
```

I have created these containers in version 0.7.5.

After update to 1.0.0.alpha2 I try to start container as

```
lxc-start -n ContainerOne

Result:

<4> init: ureadahead main process (7) terminated with status 5 
. 
.
.
mountall: mount /run [34] terminated with status 32 
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /run
```

What is the error? How can I solve this problem? I have restarted server but no luck.

**Additional Info:**

I have mounted lxc lib and cache in different file system when I installed lxc for first time. Entry in fstab file:

```
/home/lxclib /var/lib/lxc none defaults, bind 0 0 /home/lxccache /var/cache/lxc none defaults, bind 0 0
```

**Edit:**
I did update lxc while all the three containers started, Is this the problem?

Comment: Is that an old container? Do new containers have the same issue?

Comment: @Oli New containers doesn't have any issue, I am able to start newly created containers but not old containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

I had to add these lines in `/var/lib/lxc/ContainerOne/fstab` from host in all containers

```
/sys/fs/fuse/connections /sys/fs/fuse/connections none bind 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug none bind 0 0
/sys/kernel/security /sys/kernel/security none bind 0 0
/sys/fs/pstore /sys/fs/pstore none bind,optional 0 0
```